# Rails/resque trouble starting foreman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, foreman

I am trying to use Foreman to help run some simple background tasks for my Rails app, but am having trouble when starting my workers through foreman.

My worker is functioning properly when I start it from Terminal while running redis-server and rails server, using the following command:

```
bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=myqueue
```

However, I cannot get it to start up with Foreman. Here is what I have in my Procfile...

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=myqueue
```

And I get the following when running 'foreman start' in Terminal

```
14:14:39 web.1    | started with pid 48120
14:14:39 worker.1 | started with pid 48121
14:14:43 worker.1 | [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in  the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set    I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
14:14:43 web.1    | => Booting WEBrick
14:14:43 web.1    | => Rails 4.0.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:5000
14:14:43 web.1    | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
14:14:43 web.1    | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
14:14:43 worker.1 | D, [2014-04-18T14:14:43.561321 #48121] DEBUG -- : resque-2.0.0.pre.1:  Starting
14:14:43 worker.1 | exited with code 0
14:14:43 system   | sending SIGTERM to all processes
14:14:43 web.1    | Exiting
14:14:43          | D, [2014-04-18T14:14:43.568351 #48138] DEBUG -- : Registered signals
14:14:43          | I, [2014-04-18T14:14:43.574222 #48138]  INFO -- : Running before_first_fork hooks with [#<Worker Jacks-MacBook-Pro.local:48138:pledges>]
14:14:43 web.1    | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I can start up foreman when I remove the 'worker:' line from my Procfile, so I'm thinking it must be an issue with that line.

I'm using Rails 4.0.3 and Resque 2.0.0

Comment: Did you try: `env QUEUE=myqueue bundle exec rake resque:work` instead?

Comment: @Sirupsen yup. I noticed that when I run "ps -eaf | grep resque" from the command line, the pid for my worker is consistently off by +17. I'm unsure as to why this is happening, and also as to how I can fix it. Any thoughts?

Comment: The pid would be off, because what you're sending the signal to is the master rather than the worker. Your error still seems really odd to me, and not really related to Foreman. Although you do mention that it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Worker running as a daemon? When you run `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE=myqueue` is it running in the background and return to your shell prompt? Foreman doesn't play at all with daemon processes and resque workers can be configured to run as BACKGROUND=true.

If the worker **is** running in the background, disable this behavior and let foreman manage the process.

If foreman loses the connection to the process it spawned, it will kill all other processes it started from the procfile because it thinks it failed.

What's also troubling is this line:

```
14:14:43 worker.1 | D, [2014-04-18T14:14:43.561321 #48121] DEBUG -- : resque-2.0.0.pre.1:  Starting
```

It looks like you're using Resque 2.0. Is there a stable release of this yet?

Also Related:

[How to setup Rails 4, Resque 2 to run with Foreman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366042/how-to-setup-rails-4-resque-2-to-run-with-foreman)